# Manually Run Job on Play Framework 1.3

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I have inherited a system of web apps written in Play Framework 1.3 with zero knowledge transfer, and have been working through some bugs.

We have a [Job](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.3.x/jobs) that is running, but there is a bug with it. The Job runs at certain times of day, but for testing and debugging purposes I want to manually run it locally.

When I run `play run` locally the Job doesn't seem to run though.

Any ideas/pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Jobs can be triggered by now() method;

```
Promise promise = new YourJobClassHere().now();
await(promise);
```

if your job returns something (using doJobWithResult() method) you can use it like this (using List type for the example):

```
Promise<List> promise = new YourJobClassHere().now();
List list = await(promise);
```